# get dynamic list of weeks no belongs to given starting and ending dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i want get week no list by starting date and and date. as an example:
`a1 -starting date(2018/12/20).A2(2019/01/20)`. i want generate 51,52 to week no3 only, dynamically this need to change as per the given starting and ending dates. need to work different years as me example. pls help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image]

In cell D2 and copied down is this formula:

```
=IF(OR($A$2="",$B$2="",$B$2<$A$2,$A$2+7*(ROW(D1)-1)>$B$2),"",WEEKNUM($A$2+7*(ROW(D1)-1)))
```

Example workbook (it's Google sheets,but in this case the formula is identical in Excel): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kAcMfxJCo4XixXRiGqc8z9I6r5Qo2oXcdB5zSkj7_U0/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: hi can you recheck the formula please .i double checked.i got error.highly appriciate if you can check

Comment: @SandaruwanWeerasinghe It works for me as shown.  Can you please edit your original question to include a dataset that is causing the formula to error?

Comment: @SandaruwanWeerasinghe It is possible that due to regional settings, you may need to change the argument delimiter from a comma `,` to a semicolon `;` in which case the formula would be this instead: `=IF(OR($A$2="";$B$2="";$B$2<$A$2;$A$2+7*(ROW(D1)-1)>$B$2);"";WEEKNUM($A$2+7*(ROW(D1)-1)))`

Comment: i get blank excel and typed as you did.can you please forward your sample file to if you can.i typed when press enter key formula is missing parentheses error.i checked many times.can you send the excel file please.

Comment: @SandaruwanWeeransinghe I have updated the answer to include a link to an example spreadsheet.